# Unable to change brightness in Lubuntu 17.10

Tags: lubuntu, 17.10, brightness, amd-processor

I recently installed Lubuntu 17.10 on an old HP Compaq 6735 AMD Sempron SI-42 2.1GHz 3gb RAM. I'm a little new to ubuntu/lubuntu so please bare with me. I tried to turn the screen brightness up because it is kinda dim. When i use the keyboard keys associated with turning up the brightness (have to hold FN and F8). All i get is the bar on the right of my screen but it does not get brighter. I have tried using terminal and running

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness 1
```

And I get back

```
warning: output VGA1 not found; ignoring 
xrandr: Need crtc to set gamma on.
```

I have also tried

```
xbacklight -inc 10
```

And I get

```
No outputs have backlight property
```

I have also tried monitor settings and power manager but i still cannot make it brighter. It seems that the only way to make it a bit brighter is unplugging the charger and plugging it back in. That seems to be the only way to make it a bit brighter but i feel like it was brighter when it was running Windows XP. Can anyone help me with this? Is there anything i can do?